# pivot_longer() works only if id variable is dropped in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Below, I'm trying to make my data into long-form but as long as `id` variable is present in my data, it won't convert to long-form?

Is there a way I can keep `id` variable and make my data long-form?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/surv.csv')
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())

# Error: Internal error: Trace data is not square.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id)
```

If you really want `everything()` to be in long format all the columns which are going to be in long format should have the same class.

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())
```

Comment: As you must be aware one column can consist of data of only one type. You cannot have mix of integer/character/logical values in one column. So in the first case (`data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id)`), `id` column is still numeric and rest of them are characters. For the second case, since we are trying combine all the values in 1 column and 1 column can have only 1 type so we turn `id` column to character as well.

Comment: Not when it comes in long format. (`data %>% mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything())`). `value` column has integers + character values. So everything turns into character.